# How to create segment to predict income or age using Machine Learning models

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, data-science, geography, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am working on a project where I need to **create segments using geography data** like Geo key, Latitude, and Longitude. The segments should predict the average income per geo key.
The **data I have has geo keys, lat, long**, and average income, and another scenario is where I need to get the geo keys falling into the range of age (people age 18-40).
I tried to use lat and long as features to predict or classify data but the results are not promising. I also tried multiple models like Logistic regression, Random forest, and SGD classifier for multi-class classification.
I want to know what's the best way to create these segments.

Data looks like this (consists of lat and long as a geopoint):

| Geopoint | Avg. income |
| --- | --- |
| POINT(-122.425123 37.723603) | 38199.5 |
| POINT(-81.27178 28.814807) | 681428.3571 |

Comment: I converted the age ranges into classes/categories and used KNN on lat and long and tried to classify them into the classes of ages but the accuracy is less than 40%.